# Runnable thread causes imagebutton margin to "reset"

Tags: android, imagebutton

Runnable thread call causes imagebutton property to "reset"

I have a timer working fine in textbox.  Counts up every second.  I have an image button that when I click it, the top margin goes up to show that it has been selected.  The runnable call for the timer makes the imagebutton NOT move up.  If I comment the call the imagebutton moves up again on click.

The line of code in question...

```
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
```

When commented out, the imagebutton behaves how I want it to which is on click, setTop(-30).  Works great.

If I uncomment the above line, the imagebutton does not move up.  When I debug the setTop(-30) line does get hit and no errors are thrown.

updateTimerThread...

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime; 
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        textTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs)); 
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    } 
};
```

Comment: Show updateTimerThread implementation please.

Comment: Is `updateTimerThread` counteracting the other UI update?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  updateTimerThread...

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run(){
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            textTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };

Comment: Sorry new here.  Can I paste it so it keeps line breaks for you somehow?  Difficult to read like that but I'm sure there's an easier way than entering "<br>" and "<p>"?

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there please

Comment: Done.  And thank you for your patience, still learning how to post here appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for helping with the edit.  I think I understand now how to format the code like you did.